# Passing JSON object in HTTP request

Tags: json, node.js, http

I have the following:

Route file "prontuarios.js":

```
     module.exports = function(app){        
        getProntuarios =  function(request, response, next){
            var sqlCustom = request.query;  
            var connection = app.infra.connectionFactory();
            var prontuariosDAO = new app.infra.ProntuariosDAO(connection);
            prontuariosDAO.lista(sqlCustom, function(erros, resultados){            
                if(erros){
                    return next(erros);
                }
                response.format({
                    json: function(){
                        response.json(resultados);
                    }
                });
            });
            connection.end();       
        } 

        app.route('/v1/prontuarios')
            .get(getProntuarios);
...
```

and the DAO file "ProntuariosDAO.js"

```
...
ProntuariosDAO.prototype.lista = function(sqlCustom, callback){
    var _sqlCustom;
    console.log(`sqlCustom ${sqlCustom}`);      
    if (sqlCustom){
        _sqlCustom = sqlCustom; 
    }
...
```

When I call the `prontuariosDAO.lista` function, I wish to pass the "sqlCustom" parameter, but, the problem is that "sqlCustom" must be a JSON object in the function `ProntuariosDAO.prototype.lista`. However it's not happening, the sqlCustom parameter become like a string like that:

```
{ 
    limit: '10',
    offset: '2',
    orderBy: '{"field":"nome","type":"desc"}',
    whereAnd:
       [ 
         '{"field":"id","operator":"<","value":"300"}',
         '{"field":"nome","operator":"like","value":"jo%"}' 
       ] 
}
```

I have tried using the `JSON.parse` function, but it haven't worked correctly cause it is parsing the `orderBy` and `whereAnd` like a string.

Is that a way to convert that string in JSON? Am I passing the HTTP parameter correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will need to apply JSON.parse recursively to get the data being returned to you:

```
data = { 
    limit: '10',
    offset: '2',
    orderBy: '{"field":"nome","type":"desc"}',
    whereAnd:
       [ 
         '{"field":"id","operator":"<","value":"300"}',
         '{"field":"nome","operator":"like","value":"jo%"}' 
       ] 
}
JSON.parse(data.orderBy)
```